# Let $W_t$ denote a standard Brownian motion. Evaluate this integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

$$
\int_{0}^{t}d(W_{u}^2) 
$$

How can I deal with this kind of problem? If there is no function given to apply Itô's formula.

Comment: That’s merely the cumulated change up to $t$ so by definition of integrals $\int_0^td(W_u^2)=W_t^2-W_0^2=W_t^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Write $X_t = W^2_t$, then you are trying to find

$\int_0^t dX_t = X_t - X_0 $.

Now use Ito's Lemma to find the dynamics of $W^2_t$ and try to solve the SDE.